# Where is the hidden key in Dino Domain?

Tags: diddy-kong-racing-ds

I have finished most of Dino Domain, but I haven't found the key to the locked door in Dino Domain.

[image: Locked door in Dino Domain]

What track is the key hidden on? Where on the track do I need to look?

Comment: Does this question refer to a Nintendo DS game?

Comment: @sarmackie Yes - to the DS version of Diddy Kong Racing, which has enough differences from the original that I want to make sure I get information that works for the version I play.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Dino Domain key is hidden on the Ancient Lake track.

It's located at the very beginning of the track off to the right hand side.  It will be floating on an inclined ramp. As mentioned in the comments below, you'll need a blue balloon to get the boost needed to grab the key.

This video will show you where:

Comment: On the DS version, it is floating just beyond the ramp, and I can't seem to reach it by just driving off of the ramp. Any tips?

Comment: Absolutely!  You'll need a blue balloon to speed boost and that will give your the needed distance to grab it. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Oh, hey, that worked. Awesome. :D